# Catching the convergence or not by glmer in R

Tags: r, glm, convergence

I am doing simulations with glmer function. For every simulation I extract
estimates,...into a database, but I also want to have a variable that would
indicate whether simulated data converged properly or not. (I get warnings,for ex. singular convergence, false convergence,...but the estimates are given anyway).

I try

```
assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv()) # clear the previous warning
mod1=glmer(y~x+(1+x|study), family="binomial", data=test1)
warningss1=ifelse(length(warnings())>0, "yes", "no"); warningss1
```

It will always return me no even it divergent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't bang my head against the general mechanism for warnings, any more than we both already have done, anyway. There's no way that I can find to zero out or reset the warnings log. It's fairly effectively hidden away. Instead look at the object, say its name is `gm1`, you get with failure to converge. (I just reduced the sample size until convergence failure occurred.):

```
    gm1@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages
#[1] "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.10941 (tol = 0.001, component 5)"
#[2] " Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined"   

any( grepl("failed to converge", gm1@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages) )
#[1] TRUE

#with a convergent run:
> any( grepl("failed to converge", gm1@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages) )
#[1] FALSE 
>   gm1@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages
#NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem and stumbled over this tread. After some more researching I found that the following works (at least for glm-models):

```
obj <- glm(y ~ x, ...) # model specification
if (obj$converged) { 
# do stuff
} else { 
# do something else 
}
```